# How can I disable the anti aliasing in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos, antialiasing

My settings are

- OSX Mountain Lion
- java version "1.7.0_17"
- eclipse cpp 4.4.1
- Thunderbolt display

I have tried running in the terminal:

```
defaults write org.eclipse.eclipse AppleAntiAliasingThreshold 20
```

and even

```
defaults write org.eclipse.eclipse AppleAntiAliasingThreshold 40
```

and restarting eclipse everytime, but I could never get rid of antialiasing as you can see
on the picture below.

I've been struggling a lot with it, so thanks a lot in advance for your help.

EDIT: on emacs the antialiasing is well disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of the latest build of Eclipse Luna (20150109-0600), both of these have stopped working for me. It turns out the application name has changed once more -- in my case to `epp.package.jee` since I have the Java EE version. The version-independent way to do this is using the `-app` option to `defaults`:

```
defaults write -app /Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app AppleAntiAliasingThreshold 20
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work on Oxygen and later, but setting `defaults write -g NSFontDefaultScreenFontSubstitutionEnabled -bool YES` **in addition** to your answer works. Font is SourceCodePro Regular. Only need to relaunch Eclipse.app — no restart Mac or re-login.

Comment: Anything that would work in 2023? None of the above do :-(

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem moving from Eclipse Juno to Eclipse Luna (4.4.1).
The solution "defaults write org.eclipse.eclipse AppleAntiAliasingThreshold 20" worked for Juno, but didn't work for Luna.

Executing:

```
defaults write org.eclipse.eclipse AppleAntiAliasingThreshold 20
```

will modify a property plist file in ~/Library/Preferences/org.eclipse.eclipse.plist, adding the property "AppleAntiAliasingThreshold".

I noticed that after the install, Luna has created a new property file in ~/Library/Preferences/org.eclipse.platform.ide.plist.

So, doing:

```
defaults write org.eclipse.platform.ide AppleAntiAliasingThreshold 20
```

and rebooting my OS and afterwards Eclipse Luna as well, everything worked.
Hope this helps!